# Get publisher link just by doi or vice versa using latex

Tags: macros, urls, doi

I want to write a macro that is something like this:

`\get-url{10.1090/tran/8044} ------> result: https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2021-374-01/S0002-9947-2020-08044-1/`

i.e. `input=doi` and `output= url of paper in publisher webpage`

This is what I want. But it would be very nice if one can extract and return accepted and published dates and authors information. But this is just a dream, so ...!

Comment: You can join DOI number with `https://doi.org/`, such as `https://doi.org/10.1090/tran/8044`, you will get the right url. As for how LaTeX handles network-related content, I don't know about it. Maybe you can try an external program or use Lua?

Comment: For the full bibliographic information in BibTeX format you could execute a system call to https://www.doi2bib.org from your document (in this case that would be https://www.doi2bib.org/bib/10.1090/tran/8044) or some other doi resolving service.

Comment: The question is why you would want to do that though. In the Bibliography section a doi is as good as the full publisher url (or better because it takes less space). For authors, dates etc. it is better to add/check these manually as automatically generated entries are often inaccurate. Or do you want to use this in some other way unrelated to the Bibliography section? If so, then maybe you can explain a bit more in your question what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Dear @Marijn: I don't want it for bibliographic usage. I want it for some purpose to make easy some time-consuming copy-paste.

Comment: @Clara: I know it, my problem is how to extract from internet just by latex code!

Comment: Ok, could you elaborate on what "some purpose" is? That could help in giving advice on approaches within or outside of LaTeX.

Comment: @Marijn: Honstly I am TeX-Typesetter and Tex-Editor of a math journal. And I should insert doi, url (twice), accepted date, published date and all other information inside the final TeX of paper. so I am looking for a short, less confusing and easy way!

Comment: @C.F.G I don't think you need to write a program in LaTeX. You can write it in a more familiar language and call it with LaTeX, such as minted package.

Comment: @Clara: Can you give me a starting point?

Comment: TeX has no network support built in, you'll need an external tool to do the job (or resort to Lua code and most likely Lua libraries not contained in a usual TeX installation in case you're using LuaTeX). So short answer: This is impossible.

Comment: @C.F.G I'm very sorry, but I haven't actually used external programs to assist LaTeX. You can try to do a related search in tex.se.

Comment: The keyword for what @Clara tries to describe is "shell escape".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The doi resolver [doi.org](https://www.doi.org/) can return json output using the `Accept: application/json` header. You can parse this output for example with Python and extract the relevant fields. Then you can write this content to a file which you can include as part of your LaTeX document.

Part of the json output looks as follows for the paper in the question:

```json
"resource": {
  "primary": {
    "URL": "https://www.ams.org/tran/2021-374-01/S0002-9947-2020-08044-1/"
  }
},
"subtitle": [],
"short-title": [],
"issued": {
  "date-parts": [
    [
      2020,
      11,
      3
    ]
  ]
},
"references-count": 62,
"journal-issue": {
  "issue": "1",
  "published-print": {
    "date-parts": [
      [
        2021,
        1
      ]
    ]
  }
},
"alternative-id": [
  "S0002-9947-2020-08044-1"
],
"URL": "http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/tran/8044",
"relation": {},
"ISSN": [
  "0002-9947",
  "1088-6850"
],
"subject": [
  "Applied Mathematics",
  "General Mathematics"
],
"container-title-short": "Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.",
"published": {
  "date-parts": [
    [
      2020,
      11,
      3
    ]
  ]
}
```

This already contains most of the information that was mentioned in the question and the comments.

Small Python script using `pycurl` to retrieve the data:

```python
import pycurl
from io import BytesIO
import json
import calendar

doi = '10.1090/tran/8044'

# download json using pycurl
mybuffer = BytesIO()
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://dx.doi.org/'+doi)
c.setopt(c.FOLLOWLOCATION, True)
c.setopt(c.HTTPHEADER, ["Accept: application/json"])
c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, mybuffer)
c.perform()
c.close()

# parse with json library
contents = mybuffer.getvalue()
bib_dict = json.loads(contents)
# open file to be included by LaTeX
texout = open("paperinfo.tex", "w")
# start a verbatim environment to prevent problems with special characters
print("\\begin{verbatim}", file=texout)
# retrieve relevant fields from json output
print("doi:", doi, file=texout)
print("URL:", bib_dict['resource']['primary']['URL'], file=texout)
print("URL:", bib_dict['resource']['primary']['URL'], file=texout)
print("authors:", file=texout)
for person in bib_dict["author"]:
   print(person['given'], person['family'], file=texout)
print("Published date:", calendar.month_name[bib_dict['published']['date-parts'][0][1]], str(bib_dict['published']['date-parts'][0][2])+",", bib_dict['published']['date-parts'][0][0], file=texout)
# end the verbatim environment and close the file
print("\\end{verbatim}", file=texout)
texout.close()
```

Resulting `paperinfo.tex`:

```
\begin{verbatim}
doi: 10.1090/tran/8044
URL: https://www.ams.org/tran/2021-374-01/S0002-9947-2020-08044-1/
URL: https://www.ams.org/tran/2021-374-01/S0002-9947-2020-08044-1/
authors:
Anand Dessai
David González-Álvaro
Published date: November 3, 2020
\end{verbatim}
```

Show this file in a complete LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\input{paperinfo}
\end{document}
```

Resulting pdf:

[image]

Note: the workflow is a two-step process: first you manually run the Python script, this will create the file `paperinfo.tex`, and then you run LaTeX manually on the file that needs to have the information included.